# How pause the (playing) background music when the next tab button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, html5-audio

I have a HTML5 audio background music player that has one button to play and pause.  It has animate effect so music fades in or out in case of playing or pausing. Also I have 2 tabs in my page which in one of them there is a youtube video. So I would like the fade out the background music when the button of the next slide is pressed. And when the button of the slide is pressed again (back to the first slide which has no video) the music fades in and plays.

Here is the [**DEMO on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Trwc/)

And this is my jquery code:

```
$('#go').on('click',function(evt){
    var active = $('.accordion:visible');
    var nextElement = active.next();
    active.hide();
    if(nextElement.hasClass("accordion")){
        nextElement.fadeIn(1000);
    }else{
       $('.accordion:first').fadeIn(1000);
    }


});

//Music player
var beepTwo = $("#musicBeat");
beepTwo[0].play();
$("#dan").click(function() {  
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == false) {
        beepTwo[0].pause();
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            // really stop the music 

        });
        $(this).addClass("is-paused");
     } else {
         beepTwo[0].play();  
         beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
         $(this).removeClass("is-paused");
     }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
$('#go').on('click',function(evt){
    var active = $('.accordion:visible');
    var nextElement = active.next();

    active.hide();
    if(!nextElement.hasClass("accordion")){
       nextElement = $('.accordion:first');
    }
    nextElement.fadeIn(1000);

    if(nextElement.attr('id') == 'one') {
        playBackgroundMusic();
    }else {
        pauseBackgroundMusic();
    }
});

function mute() {
    muted = true;
    pauseBackgroundMusic();
}

function unmute() {
    muted = false;
    playBackgroundMusic();
}

function pauseBackgroundMusic() {
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == false) {
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            // really stop the music
            beepTwo[0].pause();        
        });
        $('#dan').addClass("is-paused");
    }
}

function playBackgroundMusic() {
    // only play music if the player is not muted
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == true && muted == false) {
        beepTwo[0].play();  
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
        $('#dan').removeClass("is-paused");
    }
}

function toggleBackgroundMusic() {
    if (muted) {
        unmute();
    } else {
        mute();
    }
}

$('#dan').click(toggleBackgroundMusic);

//Music player
var beepTwo = $("#musicBeat");
var muted = false;
playBackgroundMusic();
```

What the script now does it to look whether the next open accordion tab has the id "one". In this case the music is played. If any other tab is opened the music is paused.
The `toggleBackgroundMusic()` method is used for the player to switch.

In case you want to add more tabs and play/pause the music you can simply edit the if clause in the `#go` element's onClick function.

The working demo is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Trwc/4/

**Edit:**
And with the new muting feature:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Trwc/6/

**Edit-2:**
Fade-out fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Trwc/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is only one problem. When the music is already on mute, then you click on the next button, it is still on mute which it fine, but then u press it button again to comeback the first slide, the music starts. Which should not. because before they go the other slide it was not playing. I was thinking to add an if condition with a variable, that is true if music is playing and next button is pressed or it is not playing and the button is press.  Do u have any idea for that ?

Comment: Well, using a variable `muted` is definitely a good approach. I think the concrete solution also depends on a few other things. Should a user be able to unmute and play the background music on the page with the youtube video?

Comment: No really. That isnt important. The only this that is matter is if music is on mute already so it must not play after re opening the fist slide. and if it is playing then it must be on pause in slide to and again play when moving to slide on.

Comment: Ok, I think the update adds the requested behavior. Before playing, I simply check whether the player is muted or not. Instead of using the play methods for the toggle of the mute button, we now use the mute() and unmute() methods.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. it's perfect. Just a question, I had a `beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);` and `beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000);` to fade in and out the music, I tried ti used it in your code, but could not make it working. Can U add that too please? However I am going to choose u as the answer as u really did it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Trwc/7/

you just had to move the `pause()` to fire after the fade-out. In the previous solution we first paused the player and then started to fade out ;-)